# Windows Mobile Device center not starting

Tags: windows-mobile, wmdc

I re-installed my windows 7, and installed all software needed for my work (that is MS Visual Studio and stuff).

My problem is with WMDC (Windows Mobile Device center). Though before formatting it ran smoothly, now it doesn't seem to start :(
I plug my Intermec Pocket PC and while Mobile Adapter is enabled, wmdc doesn't pop-up the usual green window. I installed version 6.1. I tried disabling firewalls and antivirus with no success. I uninstalled it and re-installed it but with no luck.

even if I start it manually it seems to start and end immediately. Event viewer says:

```
Failed to start the Windows Mobile-2003-based device connectivity service due to Rapimgr(0x80004002) failure (see data for failure code).
```

any help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If running Win10, then as I understand it, the latest Creators Update for Windows 10, Microsoft has modified the behavior of SvcHost.exe to disallow sharing the SvcHost executable. Unfortunately, this directly affects Windows Mobile Device Center, since RapiMgr and WcesComm are configured to share the same SvcHost.

The solution to this problem requires modifying the Windows Registry.

NOTE: As always, before modifying the Windows Registry, it is advised to make a backup of the current registry.

```
Open a Command Prompt with Administrator privileges.
Enter the following commands:

REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RapiMgr /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WcesComm /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: I changed the login to 'local system', for both services (, to work properly (windows mobile-2003 base device connectivity and windows mobile-based device connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where WMDC would pop up, but Visual Studio refused to connect to an attached device for remote debugging.

After searching the internet, trying a re-install, and removing device drivers, I did a system restore to a week prior and the issue was resolved.

I still have no idea what changed in my system to cause the issue.  Just one of the mysteries of ActiveSync/WMDC.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with WMDC not starting in Win10.  I had it running then I think a Windows update messed it up.

After searching some Windows forums I came across the solution that worked for me.  I had to set the WMDC services logon account to use the Local System account and then it started and worked fine.

[WMDC Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEtGW.png)

Comment: You may also need to check the "Allow service to interact with desktop".